# How to access user's chrome apps

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am creating a new tab chrome extension and I would like to be able to list the user's chrome apps which are listed at (chrome://apps/) for easy access of apps. I was not able to find anything about this in the chrome extension API
I would like to recreate something like this default chrome apps list:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [chrome.management.getAll(function callback)](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management#method-getAll) for this kind of thing.

> Returns a list of information about installed extensions and apps.

Here is an example:

```
var types = [chrome.management.ExtensionType.LEGACY_PACKAGED_APP, chrome.management.ExtensionType.PACKAGED_APP, chrome.management.ExtensionType.HOSTED_APP];
chrome.management.getAll(function (items){
    var apps = items.filter(item => types.includes(item.type));
    apps.forEach(item => console.log(item.type, item.name));
});
```